# Can't add provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am trying to build **adhoc** application. I have updated provisioning profile in Xcode.

In Organizator > Library > Provisioning Profiles > I have verified IOS Team Provisioning Profile.

I attach my iPhone to mac and go to
`Product > Archive > Distribute > Adhoc app`, but when I try to put it on iPhone I get error:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

When I right click (in organizator) on attached iPhone device and choose **Add Device To Prov. Profile** it asks for credentials. I enter them and I get error:

> Only agents and admins are allowed to add devices to this team. Please have a team admin or agent add this device for you.

Comment: Please check your account type i.e are you admin or user.just logged into the developer.apple.com and check whether you are  able to access the provisioning profiles or not . i.e If the new profile button is enabled in the apple account then you are an admin or else only member

Comment: I am a member. User that is admin updated provisioning profile. I downloaded it from https://developer.apple.com status is active. In organizer status is valid. I just need to create ADHoc ipa file.

Comment: ok please quit the xcode and relaunch it . And then do the ipa file creation.

Comment: I did it now. And again I get: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. when I try to move ipa to device.

Comment: Clean the project and go to the build settings , select the correct provisioning profile and do your ipa file preparation

Comment: while creating ipa are you selecting the appropriate profile once it is archived? and have you set the correct profile in your code signing  field of build settings?

Comment: When I go to distribute in 'code signing identity' I got two profiles I have tried with both and still the same. In the build setting of application in 'Code Signing' section I see for example 'Prototypes iPhone Developer: My Name(5GAT...)' I choose it for debug and release. Then 'Clean', 'Build', 'Archive > Distribute'in code signing identity I see 'My Name' (no any numbers).

Comment: Do I need to do something in mac key chain? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No need to do anything in the keychain.Do one thing. Just build the project by selecting the device instead of the simulator. And then go to the products in your project navigator. There you can find the appname.app. Right click on it and copy it ,paste it somewhere and zip it. Then change that zipped file name to appname.ipa file. Test it on your device using iTunes. Let me know if it works or not

Comment: ...And then go to the products... where in product? On the menu I can't see appname?

Comment: You have  project files at the left side in the xcode. There you can find resources,products, frameworks.....

Comment: I get error. It's not valid app. Is it maybe important iPhone that I use is not registered as a developer device.

Comment: No just disconnect the device and then you can find iOS device in the xcode (iOS Device,iPhone simulator 4.0 , iPhone Simulator 5.0 ....) and do what I have explained you earlier

Comment: Yes I use IOS Device. Zip app file and change zip to ipa but I get '...could not be added to iTunes ... it is not valid app'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26380/discussion-between-tendulkar-and-1110)

Comment: FWIW, I'm getting this same error message and I =am= the team admin/agent!  (I'm the only member of my team, which I created.)